# How to change the background color of date picker

Tags: flutter, datepicker, themes

I tried lots of combinations but still can not get a solid opaque white color on the background of this picker.
There is a pinkish blend always.

This is the builder of my showDatePicker method:

```
builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
  return Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
        primary: ThemeColors.crimson,
        onBackground: Colors.white,
      ),
      dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,

      datePickerTheme: const DatePickerThemeData(

        headerBackgroundColor: ThemeColors.crimson,
        headerForegroundColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
```

[image]

In lots of examples the `backgroundColor` of DatePickerThemeData is suggested to for this. However there is always a pink or red blending that prevents a solid white background.

Answer (score 2):

The pink blend comes from [`surfaceTintColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DatePickerThemeData/surfaceTintColor.html) property of `DatePickerThemeData`, so you can set it to transparent to have your date picker reflect the actual color of `backgroundColor`.

```dart
datePickerTheme: DatePickerThemeData(
  surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
  ...
),
```

The documentation for [`Material.surfaceTintColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material/surfaceTintColor.html) explains this behavior:

> If ThemeData.useMaterial3 is true and surfaceTintColor is not null and not Colors.transparent, then it will be used to overlay the base color with an opacity based on the elevation.

Answer (score 1):

The color blend on the background of a date picker comes from [Material 3](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/design/material), which is enabled for your app (it's the [`useMaterial3`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/useMaterial3.html) option in `ThemeData`). You can, however, disable this option specifically for your date picker by providing custom builder on the [`showDatePicker`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html) function and wrap the `child` (which is a `DatePickerDialog`) with a `Theme` widget:

```dart
showDatePicker(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false),
      child: child ?? SizedBox(),
    );
  },
  ...
);
```

This will give you the Material 2 date picker dialog which by default has a white background.

Comment: What if I want to use Material 3 and a white background?

Comment: I've added a new answer to deal with Material 3 @SuatÖzkaya

Answer (score 0):

For `TimePicker` , we need another solution as below, because timePickerTheme does not have a surface tint property:

```
colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
                primary: Colors.red,
                onBackground: Colors.white,
                surfaceTint: Colors.transparent,
                /////
timePickerTheme: const TimePickerThemeData(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),
```